# MVC 4 C# CRUD DropDownList selection not getting selected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, crud, html.dropdownlistfor

I am trying to create 2 DropDownLists populated from 2 separate tables and populate a 3rd table User_Roles.  I want to do this when I create and Edit.  I am trying to assign report names to users.  Here is my model:

```
namespace ReportMenu.Models
{
    public class UserReports
    {
        [Key]
        public string user_id { get; set; }
        public string report_id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime valid_date { get; set; }
    }

    public class UsersReportsContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<ZAPR_USER_REPORTS> UserReportsDetail
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my Controller:

```
   private REPORTS_DBEntities db = new REPORTS_DBEntities();
    public ActionResult Create()
    {            
        ViewBag.Report_Names = new SelectList(db.ZAPR_REPORT, "REPORT_ID", "REPORT_NAME");
        ViewBag.User_Names = new SelectList(db.ZAPR_USER, "USER_ID", "NAME");

        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /UserReports/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(ZAPR_USER_REPORTS zapr_user_reports)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.ZAPR_USER_REPORTS.Add(zapr_user_reports);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(zapr_user_reports);
    }
```

Here is my create.cshtml view:

```
@model ReportMenu.ZAPR_USER_REPORTS

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/datepicker.js"></script>

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>ZAPR_USER_REPORTS</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.USER_ID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("User_Names", "Select a user")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.USER_ID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.REPORT_ID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("Report_Names", "Select a report")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.REPORT_ID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VALID_DATE)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.VALID_DATE, new { @class = "datetype", type = "text" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VALID_DATE)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

My dropdown lists are displayed when the create page is displayed but when the selections are selected and then Create button is clicked no values are selected....I just get Nulls in those 2 fields.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: Your not binding to a property in your model. Use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.user_id, (SelectList)ViewBag.User_Names, "Select a user")` (and ensure you re-assign the `ViewBag` properties if you return the view in the POST method. However I strongly recommend you stop using `ViewBag` and use strongly typed view models.

Comment: You should use `DropDownListFor()` helper method

Comment: It appears that 're using `@Html.DropdownList` when you should actually be using `@Html.DropdownListFor`.

Comment: Thank you Stephen!!! That worked!